# Iterate over interface/class properties and add them to an array - TypeScript 3

Tags: typescript, generics, iteration, runtime

I'm wondering if there is in the end a way in TypeScript 3 to have a possibility to iterate over interface/class properties and then add theirs names to an array? Something like keyof but in runtime.

Example of interface to iterate through:

```
interface MyInterface {
    first: string;
    second: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type system is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) by runtime, so there's nothing of `MyInterface` left to iterate through.  This is [by design](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (see Non-Goal of TypeScript #5).  Thus the answer to your question is "you can't do that, sorry."

What you *can* do is start with something that will definitely exist at runtime, like

```
const myObject = {first: "1", second: "2"};
```

and then let the compiler infer a type for that object and use this type to define the types you care about:

```
type MyType = typeof myObject;
interface MyInterface extends MyType {};
```

The above `MyInterface` is exactly the same as your original definition, but now you have the runtime object `myObject` you need to iterate through:

```
// type assertion needed because Object.keys() returns string[] on purpose
const myInterfaceKeys = Object.keys(myObject) as Array<keyof MyInterface>;
```

Hope that helps you.  Good luck!